# Create a sequence row from a filtered series

Tags: pandas, data-wrangling

I am trying to create a row that has columns from t0 to t(n).
I have a complete data frame (df) that stores the full set of data, and a data series (df_t) specific time markers I am interested in.
What I want is to create a row that has the time marker as t0 then the previous [sequence_length] rows from the complete data frame.

```
def t_data(df, df_t, col_names, sequence_length):
  df_ret = pd.DataFrame()

  for i in range(sequence_length):
    col_names_seq = [col_name + "_" + str(i) for col_name in col_names]
    df_ret[col_names_seq] = df[df.shift(i)["time"].isin(df_t)][col_names]

  return df_ret
```

Running:

```
t_data(df, df_t, ["close"], 3)
```

I get:

```
        close_0 close_1 close_2
1110    1.32080 NaN NaN
2316    1.30490 NaN NaN
2549    1.30290 NaN NaN
```

The obvious line in issue is:

```
df[df.shift(i)["time"].isin(df_t)][col_names]
```

I have tried several ways but cant seem to select data surrounding a subset.

Sample (df):

```
    time    open    close   high    low volume  EMA21   EMA13   EMA9
20  2005-01-10 04:10:00 1.3071  1.3074  1.3075  1.3070  32.0    1.306624    1.306790    1.306887
21  2005-01-10 04:15:00 1.3074  1.3073  1.3075  1.3073  16.0    1.306685    1.306863    1.306969
22  2005-01-10 04:20:00 1.3073  1.3072  1.3074  1.3072  35.0    1.306732    1.306911    1.307015
```

Sample (df_t):

```
1110   2005-01-13 23:00:00
2316   2005-01-18 03:30:00
2549   2005-01-18 22:55:00
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I don’t have data but hope this drawing helps:
[image]

Comment: What is your expected output with `df_ret`? Can you include that as well? I don't entirely understand `What I want is to create a row that has the time marker as t0 then the previous n rows from the complete data frame.` and would benefit from being able to see the actual data.

Answer (score 1):

```
def t_data(df, df_T, n):
    # Get the indexs of the original df that matches with the values of df_T
    indexs = df.reset_index().merge(df_T, how="inner")['index'].tolist()

    #create new index list where we will store the index-n vales
    newIndex = []

    #create list of values to subtract from index
    toSub = np.arange(n)

    #loop over index values and subtract the values, and append in newIndex
    for i in indexs:
        for sub in toSub:
            v = i - sub
            newIndex.append(v)

    #Use iloc to get all the rows in the original df with the newIndex values that we want
    closedCosts = df.iloc[newIndex].reset_index(drop = True)["close"].values

    #concat our data back to df_T, and reshape closedCosts by n columns
    df_final = pd.concat([df_T, pd.DataFrame(closedCosts.reshape(-1, n))], axis= 1)

    #return final df
    return df_final
```

This should do what you're asking for. The easiest way to do this is to figure out all the indexs that you would want from the original df with its corresponding closing value. Note: you will have to rename the columns after this, but all the values are there.